# XML Schema Regex

Tags: regex, xml

Regex pattern to match a string with beginning and trailing spaces containing characters in the range of A-Za-z0-9. But cannot be separated by spaces and the length limit of 10 characters.

eg:

> "  system1" is valid
>
> "sys tem1" is invalid

I have a solution with lookaheads

`^(?=.{1,10}$)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*`

But lookaheads are unfortunately cannot be used with xml schema regex.

Comment: Well I tried something like this: ^(?=.{1,10}$)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*

Comment: Should the leading and trailing spaces contribute to the length limit of 10 characters or it would be just the non-space characters?

Comment: It should be 10 characters including space characters

Comment: Your valid example is not 10 characters long!

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. But the maximum limit should be 10. So anything from 1 to 10 is valid

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below declaration:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+\s*"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

The `maxLength` and `minLength` will help applying length restriction along with `pattern` for regex restrictions.